# Tabunder Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, window

I want to be able to open a new tab on Edge, I know I can do it doing this

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

But that puts focus on that new tab. I have tried a few "solutions" online, but none seem to work with Edge (using blur() and focus() for instance). Is there a way to do this in plain JS? I am writing a TamperMonkey script to do this, so I cannot use jQuery or HTML

Comment: See if this post helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948486/focus-is-not-working-in-edge-browser/44560690#44560690

Comment: I read this, sadly I can only use JS, no html even. I have a tampermonky script that I want to be able to do this.